# React Native Android not including some built in components and APIs

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I'm having an odd problem.

Let's say I'm trying to use the `ToastAndroid` API with RN. As per the documentation, it can be included like this:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ToastAndroid
} = React;
```

However, when I try to use this line:

```
ToastAndroid.show("hello world", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
```

I get this error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'ToastAndroid.show')` which suggests it is not being included properly.

I tried removing the `ToastAndroid` line from the imports, and explicitly imported like this:

```
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
} = React;

var ToastAndroid = require('ToastAndroid');
```

And this seems to do the trick. Exact same story for other Android related things I've tried, such as `DrawerLayoutAndroid`. Why am I unable to do these imports like described in the documentation?

I am new to node and react, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but I'm seeing similar issue on v0.43.4 on Android despite what @Rhys says about it working from v0.13.0. Any chance you solved this issue in the almost 2 years since you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of React Native are you using? Including ToastAndroid in this way was only introduced in v0.13.0. If you are are using a version lower than this then you would see the described behaviour.